# Why does .NET runtime / Fusion not always load all referenced assemblies from the manifest?

Tags: .net, assemblies, il, fusion

This all started because I am trying to [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) analyze my assembly, which references [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports). Every time I do, FxCop can't find a reference to an assembly named "`BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder`".  In trying to locate this .dll, I've come to realize that it doesn't exist at all... it's not on the hard drive or the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), yet my application itself runs and displays reports just fine.

So that led me into some hunting...

In the `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll` file, if you open it in [ILDASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language#Generation), it does include the reference in its manifest:

```
.assembly extern BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder
{
  .publickeytoken = (69 2F BE A5 52 1E 13 04 )                         // i/..R...
  .ver 13:0:2000:0
}
```

However, if I open the Fusion Logger (fuslogvw) and run my application, I can see Fusion loading a bunch of Crystal assemblies, including that `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine`, but the referenced `BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder` assembly is *never even attempted* to be loaded.

So... why? How does the .NET runtime know to skip, or not load that reference at runtime? Why doesn't Fusion just load every referenced assembly recursively? I am just looking for some logic or reasoning or design intentions behind it all...

Perhaps equally as important, why can .NET projects be created that have references to .dlls, but those references aren't enforced? IMO, it is wrong that [SAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_AG) can ship Crystal assemblies that reference other assemblies that don't even get installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loads them purely on demand. The manifest is used to locate the correct assembly (including the correct version, strong name, etc.).

As long as no one requests a type from the assembly, there is no reason to load it. Note that assemblies might also get loaded just for getting the `Type` of a class, for instance through an assembly-qualified type name in a configuration file.

Comment: I guess that makes sense from a runtime perspective.  It kind of stinks from a static analysys perspective though... it looks like it is basically impossible to FxCop any assembly that references CrystalReports. At least as far as command line FxCop, where you can't tell it to skip missing references :(

Answer (score 0):

It will only load the assembly when it is actually used.  So if the code inside the assembly is never actually executed, then the assembly will never be loaded or attempted to load.